# How to get Python to open a file that I have just created?

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

So I am outputting a CSV using Python and Pandas, based on a certain criteria I have. Once building the the CSV file, I'd like to run a command that has Python open the CSV file in Excel.

Would something like this people possible?

Comment: It is, provided that Excel is set as the default application to open `.csv` files on the system or you know the location of Excel executable.

Comment: Say I know both of those things, how would I then go about doing this?

Comment: Use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) to call either the Excel executable, passing it an absolute path to your CSV file, or call your OS's default command to open a file with a known extension.

Comment: Any chance you could show me the code for that.. Sort of a newb.

Comment: `subprocess.call("path_of_excel_exe")`

Comment: Yes, but how would that open the csv?

Comment: Not `call()`. Try `subprocess.Popen(filename, shell=True)`, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the location of your Excel executable:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(("path/to/Excel.exe", "path/to/your.csv"))
```

If you don't know the location (but Excel is set as default app for `.csv` files) it depends on the OS you're using, but since you want Excel I assume it's either Windows or OSX:

```
import os
import subprocess

if os.name == "nt":
    os.startfile("path/to/your.csv")
else:
    subprocess.call(("open", "path/to/your.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for the OS to find the associated application automatically (Excel or other) *in my case on Windows, starting with the answer by zwer*.

```
import subprocess as sp

filename = 'some.csv'

sp.Popen(filename, shell=True)
```

Resorted to subprocess because `os.system(filename)` decided to start to hang.

`shell=True` resolves the problem of `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

`.Popen()` instead of `.call()` was necessary using that lone filename argument.